# How to generate a DASH manifest file (MPD file) given a fragmented MP4 file

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, mpeg-dash, fmp4

So I have a single fragmented MP4 file. Now I need to stream this fragmented MP4 file to a DASH player on a mobile device (so that user can view this video from mobile). However, I do not know how to generate the DASH manifest file for this fragmented MP4 file. Any help would be appreciated!

More info: Hope it is on-demand, not live.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to write software to accomplish this, or looking for software that can do this. If the former, Please update the question with more information, If the latter please ask on a non programming forum such as superuser.com

Comment: @szatmary If possible i am looking for any solutions that work

Answer (score -1):

It is difficult to do so.

But you can try gpac. https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/dasher#manifest-generation-only-mode

```bash
gpac -i ondemand_src.mp4 -o dash.mpd:sigfrag:profile=OnDemand
```

Here's the command right from that docs link

It didn't work for me though. Might work for you if you video is properly fragmented

Comment: ashuvssut, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)